# Serialization of a OxyPlot Chart to XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, serialization, charts, oxyplot

I generated a PageBuilder different UI-Models (TextBlocks, Images) for creating a XAMLLayout.
For this I placed all my Elements on a Canvas and save the complete Canvas to a Xaml-File (With the XamlWriter.Save-Method).

Now I need to generate Charts and serialize them.
With the OxyPlot-Library i used this code for generating the code via runtime.

```
OxyPlot.Wpf.PlotView pv = new OxyPlot.Wpf.PlotView();
OxyPlot.PlotModel pm = new OxyPlot.PlotModel();

pv.Height = 300;
pv.Width = 500;
pv.Background = Brushes.Red;
pm.Title = "Test";
pm.Series.Add(new OxyPlot.Series.FunctionSeries(Math.Cos, 0, 10, 0.1, "cos(x)"));
pv.Model = pm;

canvas.Children.Add(pv);
```

For the serialisation  I just call my Canvas and serialize the whole objects like this this:

```
XamlWriter.Save(canvas);
```

Durring this process I got an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: "The generic type" System.Collections.Generic.List`1 [OxyPlot.OxyColor] "can not be serialized."

Answer (score 0):

At this point, Generic type only has very limited support in xaml.

XamlWriter cannot serialize a property of a generic list type. You can try the following workaround to fix the issue.

```
public class OxyPlot
{
    public OxyColors OxyColor { get; set; }
}

public class OxyColors : List<OxyColor>
{

}

public class OxyColor
{

}
```

Comment: Okay, should I add this to my Main-Class ?